Movie about a journalist reporting on a trapped soul in an underground bunker
A female journalist arrives at an underground (military?) bunker to witness a trapped soul. The song Frère Jacques plays often, but I forget why. Anyway, the trapped soul escapes and unleashes hell on all the military personal and I remember a scene where it kills a solder and blood sprays against the glass. The woman narrowly escapes from the bunker and sees kids playing, then the main scientist guy gets her and takes her soul.
It was either American or British/UK.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this movie?

This sounds like "Stormhouse". The trailer is on YouTube - does it look like the film you're looking for?
Here's a review/synopsis of the film: https://horrorcultfilms.co.uk/2012/11/stormhouse-2011/
Things that fit:

Protagonist is a woman
Takes place in an underground military bunker
There's some sort of trapped entity (maybe a soul)
It starts possessing and killing everyone
The song Frere Jacques is sung by the possessed

Things that don't quite fit:

Protagonist is a medium/psychic, not a journalist

